# Summing dict values in Python 3 not working as it should?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Testing out some stuff and requires summing up values in a dictionary but, for some reason, it's not coming out as I expect it:

My script (not the actual keys/values, but this replicates the issue):

```
`my_dict = {'cat1':1, 'cat2':2, 'cat3':3}`

`sum(my_dict.values())`
```

I would expect the output to be `Out[1]: 6`, but I get `Out[1]: dict_values([1, 2, 3])`.

What's going on here?  What am I doing wrong?

I am using Sypder 5.0.5 (natively installed, MacOS BigSur 11.5.2) with a venv using Python 3.9.6....if that helps any..

Comment: does it work if you convert to list beforehand? `x = sum(list(my_dict.values()))`

Comment: else I would assume that the `sum` function is being redefined somewhere. Try `assert sum == __builtins__.sum` and see if that works. If not just call the builtin `sum` function.

Comment: Your first suggestion worked.  Just now clicked that it's being spit out as a list...still waiting for the coffee to kick in.  Thanks!!

Comment: But the question remains....why is it spitting out a list?  Is there a reason it does that? Because I would imagine that because I'm asking the computer to "sum" the values in the dictionary, that it wouldn't just say "heres the list of the values"....

Comment: That is a very good question. I'm not entirely familiar with Spyder and I also have a different Mac version, but I would likewise assume that `sum` would output a numeric value. At least on Mac Catalina with Python 3.9.0, the original code works as expected for me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `sum({'cat1':1, 'cat2':2, 'cat3':3}.values())` give you?

Comment: BTW: ```sum(my_dict.values())``` yields 6 on my system running python 3.8.5